# NTFS Drive show in fdisk -l not when I run blkid unable to mount drive

Tags: 12.04, mount, ntfs

I am unable to see a 750GB drive that is attached to my 12.04 machine using a USB 2.0 drive mate. The drive was pulled out of a Windows 7 machine and I am just trying to get all of the information off of it so I can wipe it and start over.

`fdisk -l` shows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000183e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   480094207   240046080   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       480096254   488396799     4150273    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       480096256   488396799     4150272   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdb: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 11400 cylinders, total 183143646 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x07f2837e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63      208844      835128   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sdb2   *      212992    41172991   163840000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        41172992  1465147119  1400929216    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

sudo blkid
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="dd81fbe4-0659-4eb8-9ef2-f4851ed6ff3e" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="1cb1a836-7896-4537-9e31-2cacc1a9250b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Monsters, Inc." TYPE="udf" 

sudo mount  -t ntfs /dev/sdb /media/windows
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I am unsure as to why this is not working any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should likely use:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /media/windows
```

Note the 2 after sdb. You were trying to mount the whole disk instead of the partition.

Comment: Note that the error message was telling you this.

Comment: I have tried all of them sdb1, 2, 3, and just sdb

 sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/windows
[sudo] password for mraganpbr: 
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Comment: Could the disk be corrupted?

Comment: it is possible. was just hoping to salvage something

Comment: You should probably check the disk in a Windows system to be sure. Windows support NTFS better than linux.

Comment: yeah, wish I had one :). I have tried to rid my life of them

Answer (score 0):

using two utilities photorec and testdisk I found out that the partitions were fully corrupted. I was able to pull all of the files off. 
Thanks for the help